# Facebook doesn't show Open Graph image

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

When I see like an Facebook post, when you linked like Youtube, Soundcloud etc., you get an picture. But when I do it and I post my website, it doesn’t compute.

But it doesn’t show in Facebook. The picture is 300x300 so what I did wrong?

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.statospro.se/img/StatosLogoad.jpg" >
```

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook you can use the og meta properties.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="YOUR PAGE TITLE">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://WWW.YOUR-URL.HERE">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://WWW.YOUR-URL.HERE/AND-THE-PATH-TO-YOUR-IMAGE.JPG">
```